# Initializing a list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to initlaise a list as part of a constructor argument. But I do not understand what it wants from me

```
distortion = List(
                    size = 10,
                    init = 0
            )
```

The list is of type room entity

```
    var distortion: List<DistortionCacheEntity>? = null
```

The init part is underlined in red. I dont know what to put in there or how to write it. Could someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var distortion: List<DistortionCacheEntity>? = null
distortion = List(10) { index -> DistortionCacheEntity()}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified the list is of type room entity,     var distortion: List<DistortionCacheEntity>? = null

Comment: @AndroidDev123 I updated the answer - this should work, but I don't know what actually your purpose is.

Comment: The list is size 10, am I able to specify the index out of the 10 for which the data applys to.

Answer (score 4):

The function you are trying to invoke looks like this:

```kotlin
public inline fun <T> List(size: Int, init: (index: Int) -> T): List<T>
```

So `init` here is not an Integer but rather a function. Invoke like so:

```kotlin
distortion = List(size = 10) { index : Int ->
    //Create object that the list needs to hold
}
```

Comment: index: Int, what goes into this Int part? Am I able to specify the index of the list size 10?

Comment: You will have to create an object there. In your case of type `DistortionCacheEntity`. This part will be called 10 times (i.e the size of your list) to initialize the 10 objects in the list. The index is available so that you may use it to create objects with different field values depending on the index.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to initialize a list is with kotlin library function `listOf(...)`

For example,

```
listOf(1, 2, 3) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: no reason for this to be downvoted, that is the idiomatic way of initialising a List in Kotlin. The question does not states it is looking for a list with a fixed size. Comment why something is wrong when you downvote people ...